# MVC 5 Web Api Backslash in Put request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Here is my put in my controller :

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(string name, [FromBody]string value)
{
}
```

I am currently testing it using Advenced Rest Client :

[image]

It all works fine, but my ultimate goal is to be able to put a directory in the request's payload (where the "test" is).

The problem being that a soon as there is a backslash in the string, the "value" parameter turns out to be `null` when the function receive the request.

How can I put backslashes in the payload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use url encoding. Example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

\ is %5C

Comment: Thank you! I also used HttpUtility.UrlDecode to make it back into a directory on the other side.